# Variant of Workbook.Add(object) for EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel

We're trying to step away from using Microsoft's Interop Excel dependency and switch over to EPPlus, however I'm running into an issue where I can't seem to find a replacement for Interop's Workbook.Add(object), instead in EPPlus it seems like you can only use a file as template and not an object:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.add.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's OK to use an in-memory representation of an actual Excel file, you can load a stream. For example, I have stored an Excel template as an embedded resource in a DLL, then instantiate an ExcelPackage this way:

```
ExcelPackage LoadCalculationsPackage()
{
    Assembly assembly = typeof(ExcelService).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    using (Stream s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(EXCEL_TEMPLATE_RESOURCE))
    {
        return new ExcelPackage(new MemoryStream(), s);
    }
}
```

You could do this with a completely empty Excel file.

Comment: By the way, if you think my response solves your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.